# Can I have simultaneous streams on one physical file

Tags: wcf, streaming

I have a wcf service that allow clients to download some files. Although there is a new instance of service for every client's request, if two clients try to download same file at the same time, first request to arrive locks the file until it is finished with it. So the other client is actually waiting for first client to finish as there is no multiple services. There must be a way to avoid this.

Is there anyone who knows how I can avoid this without having multiple files on servers hard disk? Or am I doing something totally wrong?

this is server side code:

`public Stream DownloadFile(string path)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);

```
        // check if exists
        if (!fileInfo.Exists) throw new FileNotFoundException();

        // open stream
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        // return result
        return stream;
    }`
```

this is client side code:

```
public void Download(string serverPath, string path)
    {
        Stream stream;
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            serviceStreamed = new ServiceStreamedClient("NetTcpBinding_IServiceStreamed");
            SimpleResult<long> res = serviceStreamed.ReturnFileSize(serverPath);
            if (!res.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception("File not found: \n" + serverPath);
            }
            // get stream from server
            stream = serviceStreamed.DownloadFile(serverPath);

                // write server stream to disk
                using (System.IO.FileStream writeStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    int chunkSize = 1 * 48 * 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
                    OnTransferStart(new TransferStartArgs());
                    do
                    {
                        // read bytes from input stream
                        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
                        if (bytesRead == 0) break;


                        // write bytes to output stream
                        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);


                        // report progress from time to time
                        OnProgressChanged(new ProgressChangedArgs(writeStream.Position));
                    } while (true);

                    writeStream.Close();
                    stream.Dispose();



                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (serviceStreamed.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                serviceStreamed.Close();
            }
            OnTransferFinished(new TransferFinishedArgs());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you reading/sending the file to the client? Please show some code.

Comment: Sory, here is server side function and client side function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Mr. Kjörling, it's hard to help without seeing what you're doing.  Since you're just downloading files from your server, why are you opening it as R/W (causing the lock).  If you open it as read only, then it won't lock.  Please don't mod down if my suggestion is lacking as it is only my interpretation of the problem w/o a lot of information.

Comment: I added code. I don't understand, how I open it as Read only? I have set FileAccess as Read, isn't that what you are talking about? Or is there something else that i have to do?

Comment: It's not necessarily the `FileAccess` causing the lock, check out `FileShare`, the third parameter available for the `FileStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should enable two threads to read the file concurrently and independently:

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
```

Comment: ok, I will try with FileShare, just I cann't try it right now. It will have to wait until I go to my office tomorrow... I'll check the answers then if it works.